# How can I insert into tables with relations?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, entity-relationship

I have only done databases without relations, but now I need to do something more serious and correct.

Here is my database design: 
[image]

1. Kunde = Customer
2. Vare = Product
3. Ordre = Order (*Read*: I want to make an order)
4. VareGruppe = ehm..type? (Read: Car, chair, closet etc.)
5. VareOrdre = Product_Orders

Here is my SQL (SQLite) schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Post (
    Postnr INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Bynavn VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Kunde (
    CPR INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Navn VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Tlf INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Adresse VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Postnr INTEGER NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT fk_postnr_post REFERENCES Post(Postnr)
);

CREATE TABLE Varegruppe (
    VGnr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Typenavn VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE Vare (
    Vnr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Navn VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Pris DEC NOT NULL,
    Beholdning INTEGER NOT NULL,
    VGnr INTEGER NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_varegruppevgnr_vgnr REFERENCES Varegruppe(VGnr)
);

CREATE TABLE Ordre (
    Onr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    CPR INTEGER NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_kundecpr_cpr REFERENCES Kunde(CPR),
    Dato DATETIME NOT NULL,
    SamletPris DEC NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE VareOrdre (
    VareOrdreID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Onr INTEGER NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_ordrenr_onr REFERENCES Ordre(Onr),
    Vnr INTEGER NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT fk_varevnr_vnr REFERENCES Vare(Vnr),
    Antal INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

It should work correctly.

But I am confused about `Product_Orders`.

How do I create an order? For example, 2 products using `SQL INSERT INTO`?
I can get nothing to work.

So far:

Only when I manually insert products and data into `Product_Orders` and then add that data to `Orders =` which makes it complete. Or the other way around (create an order in with 1 SQL, then manually inserting products into `Product_orders - 1` SQL for each entry)

Comment: Have you considered looking into 3rd party DB tools? I'm not sure what language you're using, but .NET uses LINQ, Java uses Hibernate / OpenJPA / many many others. A lot of programmers are moving away from writing SQL in favour of manipulating objects.

Comment: Yeah, I have
I love LINQ-TO-SQL really.
Sadly, I work in a team, and they only feed comfortable around SQL - I can't seem to make them learn a new tool when it comes to databases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should first create an order and then insert products in the table Product_Orders. This is necessary because you need an actual order with an id to associate it with the table Product_Orders.

You always should create a record in the foreign-key table before being able to create one in your current table. That way you should create a "Post", customer, type, product, order and product_order.

Comment: Okay, so I create an Order.
After creating it, how do I know the Onr of the just-created Order?
I need Onr when inserting the 2 products.

Comment: Could you show 3 sql sentences?

INSERT INTO Order
INSERT INTO Product_Orders
INSERT INTO Product_Orders

Or whatever it requires to get the task done.

Comment: If Onr is an auto-increment field, you can search for it with (select top 1 onr from Ordre order by onr). Then you can use the result to insert it in the Product_Orders table. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQLite for visual studio :) - the system.data one. Yeah I figured I had to do it like that, it just doesn't seem very secure. Luckily my app is 1 DB per application, but I can imagine a scenario where it goes wrong - if it is multiple applications using 1 DB

Comment: oh and yes, it is an auto_increment field

Answer (score 4):

Try this ...

first you have to insert a customer

```
insert into kunde values(1, 'navn', 1, 'adresse', 1)
```

then you insert a type

```
insert into VareGruppe values(1, 'Type1')
```

then you insert a product

```
insert into vare values(1, 'product1', '10.0', 1, 1)
```

then you add an order

```
insert into ordre values(1, 1, '20090101', '10.0')
```

then you insert a register to the product_orders table

```
insert into VareOrdre values (1, 1, 1, 1)
```

I think this is it. :-)

As the primary keys are autoincrement, don't add them to the insert and specify the columns like this

```
insert into vare(Nav, Pris, Beholdning, VGnr) values('product1', '10.0', 1, 1)
```

Use `Select @@identity` to see the onr value

Comment: Sorry, most of the primary keys are autoincrement :)

Comment: Yeah I know :)
But the issue is: when you create an ordre, how do you know the Onr when inserting products into the VareOrdre?

Answer (score 1):

I think you already have the hang of what needs to happen.  But what I think you are getting at is how to ensure data integrity.

This is where Transactions become important.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions

Answer (score 0):

Is it the SalesPrice (I'm guessing that's what SamletPris means) that's causing the issue? I can see that being a problem here. One common design solution is to have 2 tables: Order and OrderLine. The Order is a header table - it will have the foreign key relationship to the Customer table, and any other 'top level' data. The OrderLine table has FK relationships to the Order table and to the Product table, along with quantity, unit price, etc. that are unique to an order's line item. Now, to get the sales price for an order, you sum the (unit price * quantity) of the OrderLine table for that order. Storing the SalesPrice for a whole order is likely to cause big issues down the line.

Answer (score 0):

A note just in case this is MySQL: If you're using MyISAM, the MySQL server ignores the foreign keys completely.  You have to set the engine to InnoDB if you want any kind of integrity actually enforced on the database end instead of just in your logic.  This isn't your question but it is something to be aware of.

fbinder got the question right :)